# How to use external data when using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am building a dashboard(web app) to present the landslide related data. I have some external maps (slope, drainage and etc). I want to show them as layers in the web app. I was unable to find a correct way of doing so. Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: What kind of layers are in the external maps? Do you have URLs to these?

Comment: slope, Landuse, Hydrology etc. They are in my local disk

Comment: So they are files on your hard drive, ok. What format are they in (GeoJSON, Shapefile, CSV, etc)?

Comment: They are in .shp format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment that you're trying to map Shapefiles. If you want to load your Shapefiles into the map from the JavaScript API, there's a [sample here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html) that shows you how to load that file into the map.

If you'd like to add it to your [Web Map](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/what-is-web-map.htm) so that you can view it in an app, you can do that too, just go to the Arcgis.com Map page and click `Add > Layer from File` ([more info](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm)).

Comment: How about loading the shape file from the disk instead of uploading it? I want to display some local shapefiles residing on the server. I do not want user to upload them. Is it possible?

Comment: > I want to display some local shapefiles residing on the server



In that case you can follow the second step (ArcGIS.com Map Page: `Add > Layer from File`). 

Or, if you'd like to be able to update that data and see it reflected in the map without needing to re-publish, many users move the data from Shapefile into an Enterprise GeoDatabase and publish it using ArcGIS Enterprise.

Comment: I want to load Shapefiles into the map from the JavaScript API  as shown https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html), but I don't want user to upload the file. I want to give shape file (which is on the server) path through code.